# scraping table from another website

Tags: parsing, screen-scraping

How can I scrape this table with SIMPLE DOM HTML as there no TR class etc?

```
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='cashRatesTable'>
<tr class='tableHeader'>
<td>Currency</td>
<td>Equal to £1 GBP</td>
<td>Order Online<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Euros</td><td>1.1603</td><td><a href='order-travel-money/buy-euro.aspx'>Order Euros online</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>US Dollars</td><td>1.4909</td><td><a href='order-travel-money/buy-dollar.aspx'>Order US Dollars online</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>United Arab Emirates, Dirhams</td><td>5.4267</td><td><a href='order-travel-money/buy-UAE-dirham.aspx'>Order UAE Dirhams online</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I need data in arrays not as a whole

Comment: What have you tried?  In what way is that attempt not working?  I imagine any HTML parser would be able to parse this, unless there's something terribly wrong with it that I'm not noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. You can use your language of preference and use for example regular expressions. They are in all languages. If the above is just an example of what you need and you need lots of scraping done, then there are a number of tools available for that, Personally I use Netscavator (http://www.netscavator.com/) but there are others. The smart thing with this one is that it's free for private use.